# How to limit scope of a function in javascript/ jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have multiple `.js` file linked on the page that have functions with the same name like following mockup

first.js

```
function DisplayContent(data,$target) // data is string
{
     $target.html('<span>'+ data +'</span>')
}
```

second.js

```
function DisplayContent(data,$target) // data is string
{
     $target.html('<div>'+ data +'</div>')
}
```

Both the above files are referred to the page.

How to can i fix the above issue without renaming the functions.

Please correct if approach is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you keep it in one single `js` and identify on one more parameter.?

Comment: heard of Revealing module pattern ?

Comment: @ Guruprasad I can do that but i don't want to repeat the code. As each js file have their own functionality, the problem is i need to refer both js at the same time.

Comment: Where are those functions being used (respectively)? Only in the file that they were written in?

Comment: @Mayank where are you calling these functions in same file or somewhere else??

Comment: @Bergi yes, the functions are used in the file only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use namespacing in JavaScript files:

> first.js:

```
var first= {
  DisplayContent: function DisplayContent(data,$target) 
  {
     $target.html('<span>'+ data +'</span>')
  },
     [additional methods in the first object]
};
```

> second.js

```
var second= {
  displayContent: function DisplayContent(data,$target) 
  {
      $target.html('<div>'+ data +'</div>')
  },
  [additional methods for the second implementation]
};
```

Then call methods like `Namespace.method`, i.e. `first.DisplayContent()`

Answer (score 1):

It would be better i guess

```
function DisplayContent(data,$target,htmltag) // data is string
{
     $target.html('<' + htmltag + '>' + data + '</' + htmltag + '>')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling these function *only in that file itself* then you can limit scope like this:

**First.js**

```
(
  function(){
    function DisplayContent(data,$target) // data is string
    {
         //$target.html('<span>'+ data +'</span>')
         alert("first file");
    }

    DisplayContent('test','test');

    //here you can place other code
}());
```

**Second.js**

```
(
  function(){
    function DisplayContent(data,$target) // data is string
    {
         //$target.html('<div>'+ data +'</div>')
         alert("Second file");
    }

    DisplayContent('test','test');

    //here you can place other code
  }()
);
```

[**See a demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/nQlSce3QJL3wRAgIDTW1?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways.

1. You can do this in your second.js, if you dont want them to confict. This will let you use second.js independently in a page and this function would fire.

   ```
    if(typeof DisplayContent !=='function'){
       function  DisplayContent(){

     }
    }
   ```
2. You can go for a closure like Manwal rightly pointed.

However, having two functions with the same name, doesn't make much sense.  You should avoid this.

Answer (score -1):

If you add two JS files to a single page, both files will run in a single javascript context and the functions will be replaced making the result un acceptable. Thus making is impossible to do your requirement.